# spring REST API Pageable returns empty object

Tags: java, spring-rest

I know, this has been asked before.

But I did check a bunch of those answers and could not find anything with the same context that solved the issue.

The code is very straight forward:

```
@GetMapping("")
@JsonView(Views.GetView.class)
public ResponseEntity<Page<User>> getUsers(
        @ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {

    System.out.println("pageable " + pageable); 
        //output pageable Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: UNSORTED]

    Page<User>  allUsers = userRepository.findAll(pageable);

    System.out.println("page user content " + allUsers.getContent());
        //output page user content [User(id=2, name=Marshall, username=marshall44, email=marshall@gmail.com, roles=[Role(name=ROLE_USER)])]

    PageImpl<User> pagei = new PageImpl<>(allUsers.getContent());

    System.out.println("page i " + pagei);
     //output  page i Page 1 of 1 containing com.serendipity.portfolio.entity.User instances

     // return ResponseEntity.ok().body(pagei);
         // this also returns {}

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(allUsers);
}
```

I included the output of each intermediate variable so as to have a better sense of what is developing.

The request coming from Swagger UI is `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?page=0&size=20`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with `@JsonView` which did not match all properties of `User`.

Adding this to `application.properties` solved the issue:

> spring.jackson.mapper.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION=true